# Tensorflow device only acknowledges CPU even when explicitly specifying tf.device('gpu:0')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

After many attempts to verify that my nvidia quadro M4000M is capable of tensor computations,  Cuda installed correctly,  cuda toolkit 8.0 installed correctly,  deviceQuery and nvidia-smi confirms that the device is functioning properly.

[deviceQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU2BP.jpg)

[nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li8Ki.jpg)

When running tensorflow's example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a', dtype=tf.float32)
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b', dtype=tf.float32)
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False,log_device_placement=True)) 
print(sess.run(c))
```

I don't get the device mapping information and the only way I can get the  session to complete is to change the allow_soft_placement=True, which doesn't appear to use the GPU.

When allow_soft_placement = False for tf.device("/gpu:0") or /cpu:0 the error is:

> > InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> >     ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1291     try:
> >     -> 1292       return fn(*args)    1293     except errors.OpError as e:
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata) 
> >     1274       # Ensure any changes to the graph are reflected in the
> >     runtime.
> >     -> 1275       self._extend_graph()    1276       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _extend_graph(self)    1311     with
> >     self._graph._session_run_lock():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
> >     -> 1312       tf_session.ExtendSession(self._session)    1313
> >
> > InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available
> >     devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make
> >     sure the device specification refers to a valid device.    [[{{node
> >     MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
> >     _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]
> >
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> >
> > InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
> >           7 sess =  tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False,log_device_placement=True))
> >           8 
> >     ----> 9 print(sess.run(c))
> >          10 
> >          11
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
> >         885     try:
> >         886       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
> >     --> 887                          run_metadata_ptr)
> >         888       if run_metadata:
> >         889         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
> >     1108     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and
> >     feed_dict_tensor):    1109       results = self._do_run(handle,
> >     final_targets, final_fetches,
> >     -> 1110                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)    1111     else:    1112       results = []
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
> >     run_metadata)    1284     if handle is None:    1285       return
> >     self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
> >     -> 1286                            run_metadata)    1287     else:    1288       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)
> >
> > ~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
> >     in _do_call(self, fn, *args)    1306
> >     self._config.experimental.client_handles_error_formatting):    1307
> >     message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
> >     -> 1308       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)    1309     1310   def _extend_graph(self):
> >
> > InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available
> >     devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make
> >     sure the device specification refers to a valid device.    [[{{node
> >     MatMul}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
> >     _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]
> >
> > Caused by op 'MatMul', defined at:   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\runpy.py",
> >     line 193, in _run_module_as_main
> >         "**main**", mod_spec)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\runpy.py",
> >     line 85, in _run_code
> >         exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py",
> >     line 16, in 
> >         app.launch_new_instance()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py",
> >     line 658, in launch_instance
> >         app.start()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py",
> >     line 499, in start
> >         self.io_loop.start()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py",
> >     line 132, in start
> >         self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> >     line 422, in run_forever
> >         self._run_once()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> >     line 1434, in _run_once
> >         handle._run()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\asyncio\events.py",
> >     line 145, in _run
> >         self._callback(*self._args)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py",
> >     line 758, in _run_callback
> >         ret = callback()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py",
> >     line 300, in null_wrapper
> >         return fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> >     line 1233, in inner
> >         self.run()   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> >     line 1147, in run
> >         yielded = self.gen.send(value)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
> >     line 346, in process_one
> >         yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> >     line 326, in wrapper
> >         yielded = next(result)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
> >     line 259, in dispatch_shell
> >         yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> >     line 326, in wrapper
> >         yielded = next(result)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py",
> >     line 513, in execute_request
> >         user_expressions, allow_stdin,   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py",
> >     line 326, in wrapper
> >         yielded = next(result)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py",
> >     line 294, in do_execute
> >         res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)   File
> >     "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py",
> >     line 536, in run_cell
> >         return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)   File
> >     "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 2817, in run_cell
> >         raw_cell, store_history, silent, shell_futures)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 2843, in _run_cell
> >         return runner(coro)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py",
> >     line 67, in _pseudo_sync_runner
> >         coro.send(None)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 3018, in run_cell_async
> >         interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)   File
> >     "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 3183, in run_ast_nodes
> >         if (yield from self.run_code(code, result)):   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
> >     line 3265, in run_code
> >         exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 5, in 
> >         c = tf.matmul(a, b)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py",
> >     line 2053, in matmul
> >         a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)   File
> >     "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py",
> >     line 4856, in mat_mul
> >         name=name)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
> >     line 787, in _apply_op_helper
> >         op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py",
> >     line 488, in new_func
> >         return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
> >     line 3272, in create_op
> >         op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\sellersp\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensor\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
> >     line 1768, in **init**
> >         self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
> >
> > InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device for operation 'MatMul': Operation was explicitly assigned to
> >     /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [
> >     /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 ]. Make sure the device
> >     specification refers to a valid device.    [[{{node MatMul}} =
> >     MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, transpose_b=false,
> >     _device="/device:GPU:0"](a, b)]]

After searching many locations I can't seem to find where my error is.   I've run it in a Jupyter Notebook and as a script at the interpreter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Sorry for the lengthy error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed tensorflow-gpu? Tensorflow has two binary packages (tensorflow-gpu and tensorflow). https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: Yes,  I installed both using pip.   Does the order of installation matter?

Comment: You need only tensorflow-gpu package. I think you should uninstall "tensorflow" package.

Comment: If you install both tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu using pip, Tensorflow will use the CPU version by default.

Comment: When I try tensorflow-gpu only I have more problems.   I tried uninstalling both and reinstalling both and now it appear to be functioning.   It must have something to do with the order of the install.   Not sure I could explain to anyone how I was able to get things working.  ???